# Is Einstein tensor symmetric in Einstein-Cartan manifold?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Assume the connection includes an antisymmetric part $K^\alpha_{\hphantom0\mu\nu}$ i.e. $$\Gamma^\alpha_{\hphantom0\mu\nu}\equiv\tilde{\Gamma}^\alpha_{\hphantom0\mu\nu}+K^\alpha_{\hphantom0\mu\nu}$$

where $\tilde{\Gamma}$ beign the symmetric Christoffel connection. Does the Einstein tensor stay symmetric; $G_{\mu\nu}=G_{\nu\mu}$?

---

My attempt:

After grinding down some algebra, I arrived at
\begin{align*}
G_{\mu\nu}(\Gamma)&=G_{\mu\nu}(\tilde{\Gamma})+D_\rho K^\rho_{\hphantom0\nu\mu}-D_\nu K^\rho_{\hphantom0\rho\mu}-K^d_{\hphantom0\nu\mu}\Gamma^\rho_{\hphantom0 d\rho}+K^\rho_{\hphantom0 d\mu}\Gamma^d_{\hphantom0 \nu\rho}+K^\rho_{\hphantom0 \nu d}\Gamma^d_{\hphantom0 \rho\mu}+K^d_{\hphantom0 \rho\mu}\Gamma^\rho_{\hphantom0 d\nu}-K^\rho_{\hphantom0 d\mu}\Gamma^d_{\hphantom0 \rho\nu}-K^d_{\hphantom0 \rho d}\Gamma^d_{\hphantom0 \rho \nu}+K^\rho_{\hphantom0\rho\lambda}K^\lambda_{\hphantom0\nu\mu}-K^\rho_{\hphantom0\nu\lambda}K^\lambda_{\hphantom0\rho\mu}+\tilde{\Gamma}^{\rho}_{\hphantom0\rho\lambda}K^\lambda_{\hphantom0\nu\mu}+K^\rho_{\hphantom0\rho\lambda}\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\hphantom0\nu\mu}-\tilde{\Gamma}^\rho_{\hphantom0\nu\lambda}K^\lambda_{\hphantom0\rho\mu}-K^\rho_{\hphantom0\nu\lambda}\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\hphantom0\rho\mu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}(\partial_\rho K^{\rho\hphantom0\lambda}_{\hphantom0\lambda}-\partial_\lambda K^{\rho\hphantom0\lambda}_{\hphantom0\rho}+K^\rho_{\hphantom0\rho\lambda}K^{\lambda\hphantom0\alpha}_{\hphantom0\alpha}-K^\rho_{\hphantom0\alpha\lambda}K^{\lambda\hphantom0\alpha}_{\hphantom0\rho})-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}(\tilde{\Gamma}^\rho_{\hphantom0\rho\lambda}K^{\lambda\hphantom0\alpha}_{\hphantom0\alpha}+K^\rho_{\hphantom0\rho\lambda}\tilde{\Gamma}^{\lambda\hphantom0\alpha}_{\hphantom0\alpha}-\tilde{\Gamma}^\rho_{\hphantom0\alpha\lambda}K^{\lambda\hphantom0\alpha}_{\hphantom0\rho}-K^\rho_{\hphantom0\alpha\lambda}\tilde{\Gamma}^{\lambda\hphantom0\alpha}_{\hphantom0\rho})
\end{align*}
The last two parts with $g_{\mu\nu}$ are manifestly symmetric but when is the overall $G_{\mu\nu}$ symmetric? Is the vanishing of the covariant derivative of torsion ($D_\mu K^\nu_{\hphantom0\lambda\rho}=0$) enough to ensure that?

Comment: My guess is, yes the metric should still be symmetric - it shouldn't change at all. And it appears you still need some Cartan structure forms - but then I really don't know that much about it. See https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0606062.

Comment: @CinaedSimson: The OP is asking about the Einstein curvature tensor, not the metric.

Comment: @BenCrowell: on the gravitation side, $G_{\mu\nu}$ depends on the metric. Torsion come into play on the matter side.

Comment: @CinaedSimson: actually $G_{\mu\nu}$ is a function of the total connection with the symmetric part ($\tilde{\Gamma}^\alpha_{\hphantom0\mu\nu}$) written with the metric and antisymmetric part ($K^\alpha_{\hphantom0\mu\nu}$) written in terms of the torsion.
You can take all the terms with contributions from torsion and throw them in the RHS and look at it as an effective energy-momentum but torsion in essence is a geometric quantity that changes the curvature tensor.